# How to resolve this error Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my code. I am trying to access current weather time  from openmeteo API and use it in html elment, but getting this error even after adding the check.

```js
const DAY_FORMATTER =  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { weekday: 'long', month: 'long',day: 'numeric'})
    var creation_time= myData.current_weather && myData.current_weather.time
  var currentdate = DAY_FORMATTER.format(creation_time*1000)
```

Comment: At which line do you get this error?

Comment: `creation_time` is the result of a `&&` operation and therefore a boolean. So what would you expect `true * 1000` or `false * 1000` to be, and how would you apply a date format to this?

Comment: i am getting the required time at first time after reloading the page i am getting this error. I am using creation time in html element. This not the whole code of my project.Just some lines that is giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are facing is that creation_time variable is a boolean and the calculation doesn't add up. So to check if attribute inside object exists, I have added [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) that will just throw undefined and won't throw an error.

```js
const DAY_FORMATTER =  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { weekday: 'long', month: 'long',day: 'numeric'})
let creationTime = myData?.current_weather?.time;

if (creationTime){
  let currentDate = DAY_FORMATTER.format(creationTime*1000);
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = currentDate;
}
```

Hope you find this answer usefull.

Have a great day!